# Application Crashing

Tags: android

I'm new in android programing , I have two buttons in my main activity, With button number one I want to active my second activity with a text that I enter it in the first activity and with button number two I just want to active the second activity, When I tap first button application works correctly but when I tap the second button my application crashes !! Whats the problem ?
this is my main activity code :

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
        intent.putExtra("import", et.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: fix those capitals everywhere pretty please

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your log cat of the error that way we can help narrow down exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: Otra : Thank you but my system in too low that i cant run the emulator :( , can I send my app source to you to check the problem ?

Comment: User, It looks like they found out what your problem was, but next time you have a problem, it's still good to post your logcat. Logcat doesn't need your emulator. It will run on your Android device through adb. And it can even run on your device as a standalone application. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en

Comment: Stephen : For next time I'll post my logcat ! thanks for the app :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Application crashes due to NullPointerException.**
Reason: On Clicking the **Button 2** your does not provide any Intent.putExtras , so When you try access it ***second Activity*** says **getIntent.getExtras("import") is return null**

```
      if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
        Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();
        bundleObj.putInt("flag", 1);
        bundleObj.putString("import", et.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(bundleObj);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
        Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();
        bundleObj.putInt("flag", 1);
        intent1.putExtras(bundleObj);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

In secondj.class use this code to distingush button1 clicking from button 2.

```
   Intent intentObj = getIntent();
   Bundle bundleFromIntent = intentObj.getExtras();
   int checkValue = bundleFromIntent.getInt("flag");
   if(checkValue == 1)
   {
       String textFromFirstActivity = bundleFromIntent.getString("import");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
    intent.putExtra("import", et.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
}
if (arg0.getId() == R.id.button2) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main.this, secondj.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

As you mentioned, that clicking on first button works, but crashes on clicking second button. Then there is only one chance that the method call `getIntent().getBundle()` is returning `NULL` in the `secondj.onCreate()`.

You can check `NULL` for this case.

Comment: Actually I Didn't get it completely, what will my code like ? would you please write the correct code ? Thanks